# How to use Twitter Bootstrap 3 with play framework 2.3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, playframework, playframework-2.3

I have been trying adding bootstrap's js and css files to  public/javascripts and public/stylesheets application in play framework application. I donno why but I get a blank output. Is it the correct way to proceed for bootstrap v3 with play v2.3? If not what's the correct procedure to do it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**DO NOT** divide downloaded library manually, what for? It contains relative paths.

Just unzip it i.e. into `public/bootstrap` folder and include JS/CSS from there as common public asset:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
  href="@routes.Assets.at("assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css")">
<script type='text/javascript' 
  src='@routes.Assets.at("assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js")'></script>
```

of course I assume that you have default route created by Play:

```
GET  /assets/*file   controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

TIP: these folders you mentioned are just sample, it doesn't oblique you to anything... you can move/rename/delete them, whatever

Comment: Sorry but I kinda confused. Can you explain in a bit clear way ?

Comment: Confused about which part?

Comment: Did you mean unzipping the whole bootstrap v3 folder and place it in the public folder of my application in play framework?

Comment: yes, that exactly I meant :) Unzip it in some subfolder and do not manipulate its files and folders at all. Just use correct paths in template

Comment: Thanks for your interest in responding. SO if I have some thing like
in the head of my bootstrap html file

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

How am I supposed to link it in the main.scala.html of my application?

Comment: Sorry for the follow up years later - but - is it absolutely necessary to store a copy of Bootstrap locally as your solution requires? I'm trying to link to the CDN to get it to load from an external source - as it seems the OP was originally.

Answer (score 3):

In the `build.sbt` file add the following:

```
resolvers ++= Seq(
  "webjars"    at "http://webjars.github.com/m2"
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.webjars"               %% "webjars-play"       % "2.3.0",
  "org.webjars"               % "bootstrap"           % "3.0.0" exclude("org.webjars", "jquery"),
  "org.webjars"               % "jquery"              % "1.8.3"
)
```

Comment: Thanks for poining out such option as WebJars. However, it doesn't mention how to reference content of those jars. http://www.webjars.org/documentation clarifies it: /assets/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css

Answer (score 2):

in Play 2.5.x

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css")">
<script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.Assets.versioned("bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js")'></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution was as follows:

In build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "3.3.7"
)
```

In `conf/routes`, ensure you have the following line: (*This should be included by default unless you deleted it*)

```
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

In your `file.scala.html` file, you include bootstrap like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css")">
<script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js")" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

- [WebJars documentation](http://www.webjars.org/documentation)

Answer (score 0):

In the new Play 2.4 version, you should use:

```
@routes.Assets.versioned("an_asset")
```

instead of:

```
@routes.Assets.at("an_asset")
```

But remember to keep this in the *routes* file:

```
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```